# sharing a USB printer in SOHO environment

Tags: windows, windows-7, printer, soho

Here is a situation I am facing,
 there is USB printer which works only on a Windows XP machine,

there are other devices  in LAN it is a Small Office Home Office environment.

How can this USB printer attached to Windows XP machine be shared so that other laptops or users in Network who have Windows 7 or Linux on their laptops can use this printer.

The printer model number is Canon Laser Shot LBP-1210
http://www.canon-europe.com/For_Home/Product_Finder/Printers/Laser/LaserShot_LBP1210/index.asp

a [print server](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100007830%20600014444&IsNodeId=1&bop=And&SrchInDesc=IPP&Page=1&PageSize=20)  is not available to me I need to make it work in this situation only.What can I do?

**the clients are unable to connect to this.It is not a network or TCP/IP printer**

If a from Windows 7 machine  some one wants to use this printer so that he can take a print he gets an error while adding the printer to his machine  which is a Windows 7 machine (where as the printer is USB printer on Windows XP machine)

`Start--->Devices and Printers---> Add Printer---> Find Printer by name or IP address--->Selected a shared printer by name-->\\PC-Name-printer3`

and select browse it gives a message `Windows can not find  a driver for Canon LASER SHOT LBP-1210 on the network` what does this mean do I need to install some kind of software at client machine or on the machine where printer is present?

Comment: This is decidely not a professional level system administration question but nonetheless, here you go: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457001.aspx

Comment: Why isn't a print server an option here? Without one, your Windows XP system becomes an unnecessary dependency in order for other users to be able to print.

Comment: Yes exactly I do not have the hardware to have print server.The printer does not have a capability to connect to Ethernet switch.

Comment: Any USB printer can work with USB print servers. Many routers and NAT devices have this functionality built in. Or you can buy [a dedicated server](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&N=100006519&isNodeId=1&Description=usb+print+server). But whether you use a print server or a PC, you need to [download the printer driver](http://software.canon-europe.com/products/0000525.asp) and install it on the PC that wants to use the printer.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch I have downloaded the software from the link you gave many many softwares from the same link even before posting the question here such as a file named LBP-1210_R110_V110_Win_x32_EN_7 but when I try to install it it does not work out.(Installing on the Windows 7 machine) on Xp machine printer is connected and there one can take print out but not from Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using an [HP JetDirect 175x USB print server](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF05a/18972-18972-236253-34214-64302-28830.html?dnr=1) (or similar) as an approach to centralizing access to the device. This would eliminate the dependency on the direct-attached Windows XP system.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows (client) machines connecting to that printer over printer sharing, download/install drives from following link

```
http://www.canon.co.uk/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/Laser/Laser_Shot_LBP1210.aspx?type=download&page=1
```

You can choose language and OS version, then click search. That will narrow down the download list for you.

> Canon CAPT Printer Driver File version: R1.10 V1.1 Operating
>   system(s): Windows 7, Windows Vista

PS: There is not driver for 64-bit Windows. But you can still try the Linux driver, it contain BOTH 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: I downloaded the driver you suggested but this is not the correct file it gives a file nsdi.exe which tries to search for printer based on mac address of printer where as this printer does not have a mac address to be used with port etc..

Comment: on a Windows 7 machine with the file you said Start--->Devices and Printers---> Add Printer---> Find Printer by name or IP address--->Selected a shared printer by name-->\\PC-Name-printer3 now comes the step to add the driver in this step it is unable to find the driver from the downloaded (unzipped) file

Comment: Uopdated, should use printer drive. I post the network config utility before.

Comment: Hmmm I am afraid though on manufacturer website in drivers it mentions Windows 7 but those drivers actually do not work

Comment: How does it not work? Refuse to install? Or cannot find driver from the download folder?

Comment: OK, I tries it, if your Windows 7 is 64-bit, it will not work. Canon only has 32-bit Windows driver for this printer. But you can still try the Linux driver, it contain BOTH 32 and 64 bit.